# Need an explanation of a particular expression transformation

Tags: transformation, fractions

Please, I need an explanation of the one transformation. I have the equation set and its solution.

$$
\begin{cases}
    \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{z} + \frac{z}{x} = 3\\\\
    \frac{y}{x} + \frac{z}{y} + \frac{x}{z} = 3\\\\
    \ x + y + z = 3
\end{cases}
$$

In the solution three new variables were introduced:

$$
u = \frac{x}{y}; v = \frac{y}{z}; w = \frac{z}{x}
$$

And then using this new vars equation set became this:

$$
\begin{cases}
    \ u + v + w = 3\\\\
    \frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v} + \frac{1}{w} = 3\\\\\\
    \ uvw = 1
\end{cases}
$$

I can't understand how the $x + y + z = 3$ has become the $uvw = 1$. Can someone explain what have been done here?

My appreciation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
uvw = \frac{x}{y}\frac{y}{z} \frac{z}{x}=\frac{xyz}{yzx}=1
$$